# title attribute to Grid View template field

Tags: javascript, .net, c#-3.0

I am using a Grid View in which I have defined "TemplateField" and then its property Header Text and SortExpression = true.

When viewing in browser i see that it creates anchor element with some javascript.

How can I give title tag to this anchor in code. Basically I want to show title attribute like this "Click to Sort".

But I haven't see any property for this. how can i do this with or without javascript or with c#.

Here is my code

```
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="Username">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by using jquery.

For help who have same problem I have done following process.

I have created a css class for header row th and then adding title to this th using jquery by following code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#content table tr.rowH th a').attr("title", "Click to Sort");
    });
</script>
```